# How to create a periodic request using work manager that operates only while app is in foreground

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I want to make a periodic background request that needs to be done only while the app in the foreground, so for example, if the period time is 24 hours so after 24 hours the work manager should wait to perform this request when the application is in the foreground.
Does anybody know how to make it or if there is a better way to implement this behaviour?

Comment: Silly question but, why the need to use work manager if you're going to so it while the app is open/foreground? Why not use a foreground service to perform the job for you? Or, if you still want to add other "constraints" you can fire the work manager from the foreground with "do it asap" kinda thing (the exact start time will be determined by the actual Work manager anyway).

Comment: So the check to see if 24 hours have elapsed is up to you, but it's quite easy to figure this out, assuming you record the last time the app was foreground (see [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.html) for example)

Comment: as you said because I want to add other constraints and some other functionalities of the work manager, whatever I didn't think it was that hard, I will manage wzout using WorkManager

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from (on app Foreground detection) check if more than 24 hours have elapsed, and if so, scheduling WorkManager to do what you need now, else, do nothing (since you only need this to run when the app is foreground, this will happen next time this check is performed and more than 24 hours elapsed). Doesn't that do what you need?

Comment: Actually, I think I have to check if the app is in the foreground or not in the doWork func since work manager can start the request after the app is closed, It actually takes few seconds to start it, and if the request is completed successfully I will update the cache with the last time it was successful because I still may start the workrequest and some error may still occur.

Comment: So your requirement is not that the job starts when the app is foreground but *also* that the app is foreground while the job is being performed? I get it that it takes time, but if you ONLY want to do it when the app is 100% foreground, I'd use a bound service or similar for that, since only your main process will determine that. What happens if the job starts and the user goes to background? does the job still continue?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes it continues, I think I will do it in the normal way, I will check my constrains and start this task on a background thread using coroutines, cuz the whole idea of using workmanager was that I could use periodic request and some constraints.

Comment: Good luck, don't hesitate to post another question if needed :)